# Korrektes Gegenteil von „folgen“

Tags: verb, single-word-request, verb-choice

In einigen Apps ist mir die Schaltfläche *Entfolgen* aufgefallen, die das Gegenteil von folgen bedeuten soll. Entfolgen hört sich in meinen Ohren falsch an. Ein korrektes Gegenteil wäre *nicht mehr folgen*, das ist nur für die meisten App-Schaltflächen zu lang.

Gibt es ein kürzeres oder korrektes Gegenteil von *folgen*?

Comment: Willkommen bei uns =)

Comment: "Folgen" ist an sich schon Blödsinn. Im Deutschen müsste es eigentlich "verfolgen" (im Sinne von *ich verfolge die Nachrichten im Fernsehen*) heissen. Es ist daher ein bißchen müssig, das Gegenteil zu einem blödsinnigen Begriff zu suchen... Aber: Wenn man die Nachrichten *nicht mehr verfolgt*, **ignoriert** man sie oder man **verfolgt sie nicht**. Also wäre eigentlich *ignorieren* richtig.

Comment: Das Gegenteil von folgen ist führen. Eine Folgschaft zu kündigen ist die Neutralisierung des Folgens. Das Gegenteil von heiß ist nicht lau, sondern kalt.

Comment: @tofro: Eine Sendung kannst Du verfolgen, aber wenn Du eine Person verfolgst wird das üblicherweise als unfreundlicher Akt wahrgenommen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das Problem tritt auch schon im Englischen auf, dort wurde das neue Verb *to unfollow* für exakt diesen Zweck geschaffen. Semantisch ist es ungefähr so sinnvoll wie *entfolgen*.

In der Regel bezeichnet *folgen* einen Prozess.

> Ich folge jemandem.

Dieser Satz wird normalerweise so aufgefasst, dass ich jemanden auf längere Zeit hinterhergehe, oder – neuerdings – alle seine Beiträge bekommen möchte. Für den Anfangsklick, der üblicherweise mit *folgen* betitelt wird, ist das Verb prinzipiell auch schon falsch – auch wieder nicht anders als im Englischen, wo »I follow« etwas seltsam wirkt.

Jetzt war es nötig, ein kurzes Wort zu finden, das den Beginn dieses Abonnements ausdrücken kann; Englisch hat sich für *to follow* entschieden. Umgekehrt muss man das Abonnement auch beenden können, und so falsch wie *to follow* für den ersten Fall ist, so logisch ist es, *to unfollow* für den zweiten herzunehmen. Aus dieser Warte ist *entfolgen* eine recht gute Wortwahl.

Zusammengefasst: *folgen* (*to follow*) sollte eigentlich schon *zu folgen anfangen* (*start following*) oder ähnliches sein. Fälscher als sein Gegenteil kann *entfolgen* (*to unfollow*) kaum sein, solange für *nicht mehr folgen* (*stop following*) kein Platz ist.

Comment: "Zu folgen anfangen" ist so sinnvoll wie "zu drucken anfangen", "zu kopieren beginnen" u.ä.

Comment: @userunknown Finde ich nicht. *Kopieren* und *drucken* sind einmalige Tätigkeiten (in der Regel), die einen definierten Anfang und ein Ende haben – und beide folgen einander recht schnell. *Folgen* ist dagegen *per se* als ewig andauernder Prozess angelegt.

Comment: Von der Ewigkeitsbehauptung abgesehen, die offensichtlich falsch ist, wo ist die Relevanz? "Ich folge jmd." ist eine Tätigkeit die lang oder kurz dauern kann. Man kann auch jemandem nur für 2 Tage oder Stunden folgen, etwa während man auf einer Konferenz ist der Konferenzleitung. Kopieren und Drucken haben zwar ein von vorneherein definiertes Ende, aber welche Relevanz hat das? Anfangen muss man damit trotzdem und zwar damit, dass man dem Rechner den Befehl gibt, wie beim Folgen.